# How to dynamically load linkedin share button?

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I am loading dynamically content on my web site and I need to create social media buttons after the ajax function, when i get necessary information. I found great solutions for facebook and twitter, but I can't find the working solution for linkedin. 
Hope my question is clear... Thanks in advance for smart answers!

EDIT: I found a solution.

```
var din ='<script id="holderLink" type="IN/Share" data-url="http://kitchenprague.com/news.php?id='+val.id+'" data-counter="right"></script>';
$(".linkedinDetail").html(din);
IN.parse();
```

Comment: Does the button load in approprite moment this way ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746030/linkedin-button-delay-in-apparition-even-after-use-of-done-function . thanks

Answer (score 1):

The full solution as stated by hjuster is...

```
var din ='<script id="holderLink" type="IN/Share" data-url="http://kitchenprague.com/news.php?id='+val.id+'" data-counter="right"></script>';
$(".linkedinDetail").html(din);
IN.parse();
```

But let me provide some explanation, because explanation is great!

Build a script tag to hold your share URL data...

```
var din ='<script id="holderLink" type="IN/Share" data-url="http://kitchenprague.com/news.php?id='+val.id+'" data-counter="right"></script>';
```

Simply append the URL data to the page...

```
$(".linkedinDetail").html(din);
```

According to the [Official LinkedIn Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/lts/apply-with-linkedin/customer-configuration?src=aff-lilpar&veh=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&trk=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&clickid=SRPXd0wT8xyORz2wUx0Mo38TUki1Iq1twXmmUQ0&irgwc=1), "In order to reload the widget on a single page application, use in.parse()," so...

```
IN.parse();
```

*Hope this helps someone out there!*