# Share dynamic URL link on linkedin

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

In HTML code I written script with `data-url` statically which working fine but my question is how to share link which is generated dynamically?

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://www.everdrobe.com/rate/551107c763eef/recent" data-counter="top" id="linked_url"></script>
</div>
```

**Linkedin Script**

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
```

I think `script` executed only once at load time that's why it not working any other way Can I share?
Help should appraciate.

Comment: You can reload your share button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178996/how-to-dynamically-load-linkedin-share-button

Comment: What did you do to reload your dynamic URL? Are you reloading your button using IN.parse();

Comment: I want to share URL link which is dynamically generated like `data-url`

Answer (score 1):

In your js file,

```
$("#linked_url").click(function() {

    window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url="
                + $(this).data("url")
                +"&title=",'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share on LinkedIn using a format like so...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

So, of course, then you can share in JS dynamically with just...

```
var yoururl = "yoursite.com?something=somethingelse&test=test2";

$('.share-link').html(
    '<a href="' +
    'https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=' +
    encodeURIComponent(yoururl) +
    '">Share on LinkedIn</a>'
);
```

If you want to prepolulate things like title, description, thumbnail, etc., then check out the OpenGraph tags ase described by the **[Official LinkedIn Shareable Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.